# Could not resolve: org.jetbrains.pty4j:pty4j:0.9.8

Tags: gradle, pty

In my **build.gradle** file.

```
repositories {
maven {
url  "https://jetbrains.bintray.com/pty4j"
}
mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {

implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.pty4j', name: 'pty4j', version: '0.9.8'

}
```

If I build my project it comes like this

```
Could not resolve org.jetbrains.pty4j:pty4j:0.9.8.

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at 
  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtRfS.png)

How can I solve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular artefact is not provided by `MavenCentral()` but rather by the Spring Release Repository. One useful trick to find out which repositories provide a given artefact is to seek your artefact [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.pty4j/pty4j/0.9.8) and pay attention to the **repositories** link provided.

You'll need then to change your Gradle config to something like:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://packages.jetbrains.team/maven/p/ij/intellij-dependencies" }
}
```

Comment: I tried this answer but not worked

Comment: did you fix this already? I've edited my answer to add the repo that worked for me and tried a build that went successfully